# Java Web Service "no nativemvm in java.library.path"

Tags: java, matlab, web-services

I am creating a web service with the following code:

```
package com.tesis.service;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException;
import com.mathworks.engine.*;

public
 class CNNPredict 
{
    public String cNNPredict(int[] Image, int Height, int Width) throws Exception
    {
        String FilePath =   "/home/riosgamarra/Documents/MATLAB/TesisGamarrarios";
        char[] CharFilePath = FilePath.toCharArray();
        MatlabEngine eng = MatlabEngine.startMatlab();
        eng.feval("cd", CharFilePath);
        String result = eng.feval("CNNPredict",Image,Height,Width);
        return result;
    }
}
```

It works apparently fine because the WSDL page opens without problems.
I am using Matlab engine so I had to Add the .jar file , I added it on `ServidorTesis/ReferencedLibraries` and also in `ServidorTesis/WebContent/lib`

Also I added this .jar  on the web deployment Assembly:

[Web Deployment Assembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJQOF.png)

The problem is  when I try to use my client:

```
public class CallWS {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws CNNPredictExceptionException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CNNPredictExceptionException
    {
        CNNPredictStub stub = new CNNPredictStub();
        CNNPredict cnn = new CNNPredict();
        BufferedImage img = null;
        System.out.println("Reading image ...");
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/riosgamarra/Documents/MATLAB/TesisGamarrarios/101_ObjectCategories/laptop/image_0009.jpg"));
        int[] UnrolledImage = convertToGray(img);
        cnn.setImage(UnrolledImage);
        cnn.setWidth(img.getWidth());
        cnn.setHeight(img.getHeight());
        System.out.println(stub.cNNPredict(cnn).get_return());

    }
    private static int[] convertToGray(BufferedImage image)
    {
        final int width = image.getWidth();
        final int height = image.getHeight();
        int red;
        int green;
        int blue;
        int gray;
        int[] result = new int[width*height];
        for(int c = 0; c < width; c++)
            for(int f = 0; f < height; f++)
            {
                Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(c,f));
                red = color.getRed();
                green = color.getGreen();
                blue = color.getBlue();
                gray = (red+green+blue)/3;
                result[height*c + f] = gray;
            }
        return result;
    }
}
```

It throws the following error: `[ERROR] no nativemvm in java.library.path` and  `Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nativemvm in java.library.path`
and the code does not run.

I remember that I had the same error when I was doing this web server as a desktop application and fixed  it adding this path : "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64" to Native Library Folder configuration:

[How I fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFjSG.png)

But now I do not know how to solve this:

I have read that I need to change something in "Catalina_OPTS"  but I do not understand what is this or how to change it, I have followed lots of instructions but nothing works.

Thanks for your time.